# Share internet through Proxy Server?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, proxy

I know that a proxy server can be used to secure a network, everything is encrypted, to connect from other country as if i were in another, surf anonymously... But what i don't know if it's possible and how to do is to give internet access through a proxy server, i mean, can i create a VPN and give access to internet through a proxy server?

For example: i have a server at Amazon EC2, i would like to get internet access from my Android phone through a VPN using the server i have at amazon as a proxy server, can i do that? will the phone have the speed of internet as the amazon server?

Comment: Why the downvote? i mean, can't i ask how to's? or information questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can set up a proxy at a server and route your connection through it. No VPN is required to forward your internet. It does require internet access through WiFi or some similar source.

However, **you will be capped** by the speed of your phone's upload/download bandwidth, which is not much.

A easy to setup proxy server is [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/) if you are still looking to host one.

Comment: There's no way to get the Internet speed of the server on a client (e.g My Phone)?

Comment: It's physically impossible sadly. Your phone can only transmit so much data at a time. However, if a program you are using is something that requires a lot of processing power such as generating a 3 dimensional graph or something more complex from a file you can offload it to the server for processing and view the result/download the data on your phone. [Wikipedia on Bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)#Internet_connection_bandwidth)

Comment: What about getting free Internet access ? Some guys use proxy servers to get free Internet access, but how?

Comment: Psiphon handler let's u somehow get free Internet access, how could I setup a proxy server so that I get Internet access through an app like psiphon or openvpn?

Comment: **You have to be getting internet access from somewhere to connect to a proxy server.** If you are talking about going on sites not accessible from other locations, they can go to a place with free WiFi such as McDonalds or Starbucks and proxy to their remote server so they can access their files/accessible content. [Wikipedia on Proxy Servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to use a proxy server. If you set up a proxy server somewhere, you can configure a browser on your computer, phone, tablet, etc. to route its HTTP/HTTPS traffic through the proxy server. You can also set up proxy servers to handle other types of traffic, such as email, etc. In such cases, your device will send any requests that would normally go directly to a website, email server, etc. to the proxy server, which would forward the requests to the appropriate destination server, whether it be various web servers, an email server, etc. From your phone, your access speed to a website, if you are using a proxy server as an intermediary, will be limited by the available bandwidth between your phone and the proxy server and also by the bandwidth between the proxy server and other systems on the Internet to which the proxy server will be forwarding your network traffic. So, yes, the phone will have the access speed available from the proxy server to other systems on the Internet, but only for the part of the network path from the proxy server to those other systems. If your phone has a slow connection to the Internet, e.g., because of a limited bandwidth from your Internet Service Provider or the phone service provider, that will slow your connectivity to the proxy server and thus your overall network performance.

Comment: So you're saying that if my ISP gives me the 1 Mb/s and my proxy server has a connection of 300 Mb/s, I'll be still getting only 1 Mb/s of Internet speed because of my ISP?

Comment: Yes, you will be limited by the 1 Mbs from your ISP, no matter what bandwidth the proxy server has available to it.

Comment: Mmmm, is there a way to get the most of the ISP without contract?

Comment: Whether you need to sign up for a long-term contract for Internet service will depend on the ISPs in your area. You may get a discounted price if you agree to a longer-term contract.